# assign a specific values as NA

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation

how to assign df$v2==0 as NA

```
v1 <- c("1","2","3","4","5")
v2 <- c("a","b","c","d","0")

df <- cbind(v1,v2)
df
```

Expected answer would be

```
    v1  v2 
[1,] "1" "a"
[2,] "2" "b"
[3,] "3" "c"
[4,] "4" "d"
[5,] "5" "NA"
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `cbind` unless you explicitly want data to be a matrix. In most of the cases dealing with dataframe is better so use `df <- data.frame(v1,v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` to create dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign directly :

```
df$v2[df$v2 == 0] <- NA
df

#  v1   v2
#1  1    a
#2  2    b
#3  3    c
#4  4    d
#5  5 <NA>
```

Or with `replace`  or `ifelse`.

```
df$v2 <- replace(df$v2, df$v2 == 0, NA)
df$v2 <- ifelse(df$v2 == 0, NA, df$v2)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(v1,v2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R

```
df[ df$v2 == 0, "v2"] = NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have `data.table` (recommended option if your dataset is voluminous) that uses update by reference (`:=` operator)

```r
dt <- data.table('v1' = v1,'v2' = v2)
dt[v2 == "0", v2 := NA_character_]
```

By the way, you use characters but it looks like you could use numeric format for `v1`

Answer (score 1):

Since your *df* is actually a string `matrix`, you can use:

```
df[df[, 2] == "0", 2] <- NA_character_
```

Output:

```
df
     v1  v2 
[1,] "1" "a"
[2,] "2" "b"
[3,] "3" "c"
[4,] "4" "d"
[5,] "5" NA
```

But I would recomend one of the `data.frame` solutions posted here.

Data:

```
v1 <- c("1","2","3","4","5")
v2 <- c("a","b","c","d","0")
df <- cbind(v1,v2)
```